# Unexpected problems after importing WP data

Tags: users, import, export

I had to move my solution from one server to another. I therefore Exported all data so that I could import this on the new server.

All worked fine except users.

If I want to edit my own profile, all is well.
But if I try to edit another user profile, I get these error messages:

> Notice: Undefined property: WP_User::$rich_editing in
>   I:\Development\wamp\www\storelocator\wp-admin\user-edit.php on line
>   199

and

> Notice: Undefined property: WP_User::$nickname in
>   I:\Development\wamp\www\storelocator\wp-admin\user-edit.php on line
>   285

After I imported data from the other server, all nicknames have this text:
`<br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan=`

If I click `Update`, data is stored and the error messages goes away.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons could be that while exporting/importing the data the server debug or 'WP_DEBUG' must have been true for warnings/errors. Hence they must have cropped up in the export file.